# R/Shiny: Change plot ONLY after action button has been clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I am setting up a small shiny app where I do not want the plot to change unless the action button is clicked. In the example below, when I first run the app, there is no plot until I click the action button. However, if I then change my menu option in the drop-down from Histogram to Scatter, the scatter plot is automatically displayed even though the value for input$show_plot has not changed because the action button has not been clicked.

Is there a way that I can change my menu selection from Histogram to Scatter, but NOT have the plot change until I click the action button? I've read through several different posts and articles and can't seem to get this worked out.

Thanks for any input!

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Main",
             headerPanel(""),

             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput('plot_type', 'Select plot type', c('Histogram','Scatter'), width = "250px"),
               actionButton('show_plot',"Plot", width = "125px"),

               width = 2

             ),

             mainPanel(
               conditionalPanel(
                 "input.plot_type == 'Histogram'",
                 plotOutput('plot_histogram')
               ),

               conditionalPanel(
                 "input.plot_type == 'Scatter'",
                 plotOutput('plot_scatter')
               )
             ))
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)

function(input, output, session) {

  ### GENERATE SOME DATA ###
  source_data <- reactive({
    mydata1 = as.data.frame(rnorm(n = 100))
    mydata2 = as.data.frame(rnorm(n = 100))
    mydata = cbind(mydata1, mydata2)
    colnames(mydata) <- c("value1","value2")
    return(mydata)
  })

  # get a subset of the data for the histogram
  hist_data <- reactive({
      data_sub = as.data.frame(source_data()[sample(1:nrow(source_data()), 75), "value1"])
      colnames(data_sub) <- "value1"
      return(data_sub)
  })

  # get a subset of the data for the scatter plot
  scatter_data <- reactive({
      data_sub = as.data.frame(source_data()[sample(1:nrow(source_data()), 75),])
      return(data_sub)
  })


  ### MAKE SOME PLOTS ###
  observeEvent(input$show_plot,{
    output$plot_histogram <- renderPlot({
      isolate({
        plot_data = hist_data()
        print(head(plot_data))
        p = ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = value1, y = ..count..)) + geom_histogram()
        return(p)

      })
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$show_plot,{
    output$plot_scatter <- renderPlot({
      isolate({
        plot_data = scatter_data()
        print(head(plot_data))
        p = ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = value1, y = value2)) + geom_point()
        return(p)

      })
    })
  })

}
```

Comment: In your desired behavior what extra purpose does the `actionButton()` serve? If you want to change plots based on user input then the combo of `selectinput()` `conditionPanel()` already does that for you. I don't see a need for `actionButton()` at all.

Comment: @Shree Hi, thank you for the response. I agree that having the action button is a bit useless in this example. This is a very simplified example of what I am really doing. If there were additional input options in the menu(some of which may or may not be required), I do not want any action to take place (to display the scatter plot) until the plot button has been clicked.

Comment: In that case your calculations based on other input would automatically recalculate the graphs. If there are multiple inputs you can do the data manipulation in `eventReactive()` and then feed output to plot so plot updates only when `actionButton` is pressed. Making the plot appear-disappear is not necessary and just complicates the code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your desired behavior I don't see a need for `actionButton()` at all. If you want to change plots based on user input then the combo of `selectinput()` and `conditionPanel()` already does that for you.

On another note, it is not good practice to have output bindings inside any reactives. Here's an improved version of your server code. I think you are good enough to see notice the changes but comment if you have any questions. -

```
function(input, output, session) {

  ### GENERATE SOME DATA ###
  source_data <- data.frame(value1 = rnorm(n = 100), value2 = rnorm(n = 100))

  # get a subset of the data for the histogram
  hist_data <- reactive({
    # reactive is not needed if no user input is used for creating this data
    source_data[sample(1:nrow(source_data), 75), "value1", drop = F]
  })

  # get a subset of the data for the histogram
  scatter_data <- reactive({
    # reactive is not needed if no user input is used for creating this data
    source_data[sample(1:nrow(source_data), 75), , drop = F]
  })

  ### MAKE SOME PLOTS ###
  output$plot_histogram <- renderPlot({
    req(hist_data())
    print(head(hist_data()))
    p = ggplot(hist_data(), aes(x = value1, y = ..count..)) + geom_histogram()
    return(p)
  })

  output$plot_scatter <- renderPlot({
    req(scatter_data())
    print(head(scatter_data()))
    p = ggplot(scatter_data(), aes(x = value1, y = value2)) + geom_point()
    return(p)
  })
}
```